# How to make dynamic API calls in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using the following Typescript function to get access to API data:

```
export class BomService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  GetAllBomList(): Observable<IBom[]> {
    return this.http.get<IBom[]>('http:192.168.10.1:5000/api/bom/getallboms');
  }
}
```

When I use my own computer I can load data completely but when I'm trying to get access through Internet, the UI is loaded but the data cannot be fetched. The reason is Http address. Both the API and the UI are hosted in the same server using IIS. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This API call will fail if you're accessing the app through the internet as you've hard-coded a private IP address into your http request. The request will not be hitting your server.

Comment: @Swemoph What is the right way to make API Calls when I intended to use my app through both local network and Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular < 15 has an environments folder. Angular 15+ you need first call `ng g environments` inside your project. Then you see this folders/files (names can be different of the files)

[image]

*The files looks like this:*

**environment.development**

```
export const environment = {
  serverPath: 'http://localhost:3000',
};
```

**environment** (production)

```
export const environment = {
  serverPath: 'http://123.123.123.123:3000', // Server path
};
```

The rest of the magic do Angular for you. So in your service/component or what you want you need to import the file like this:

**Service**

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

...

  GetAllBomList(): Observable<IBom[]> {
    return this.http.get<IBom[]>(environment.serverPath + '/api/bom/getallboms');
  }
```

Read all about environments [here](https://angular.io/guide/build). But in short: In the `angular.json` file you will find the environments files. One for `dev` and one for `production`. If you run `ng build` Angular will replace the `dev` file with the `production` file. You need to do nothing.

Comment: Lets explain my problem with more detail. I deploy my Angular project in the same server the API has been deployed. There are some users who use local network to access the server, and there some other users who use Internet to connect the server. the problem is that if I set `serverPath` to local IP, the users who connects through Internet will fail to fetch data from API. if I set `serverPath` to Internet IP, the users who connect through local network will fail to fetch data from API. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It's complete the same from where you wanna get the data. From localhost, or from outside the server-ip is the same. Whats your problem can be is CORS. By the way: Is your server local and people from "outside" wanna connect? Is your server then in the internet? And this was not your question at start. So its not fair to remove the upvote and so on.

Comment: The server is a local computer which is connected to other local computers. The server has Internet access and a static IP provided by ISP. People can connect to the IIS through this static IP.

Comment: Which error occurs on the frontends of the other clients?

Comment: You have hard-coded `http://123.123.123.123:3000` in your environment so if someone tried to access the site through Internet, the data will call `http://123.123.123.123:3000/.....` and this is wrong. I tested it.

Comment: That was a example! You need to replace your real IP!

Comment: What is the difference between `environment.development` and `environment`? If I biuld the project using `ng biuld` and deploy it in IIs and use local network to access the site, which one is used?

Comment: Consider that my server IP  on local network is `192.168.10.1` and the IP provided by the ISP is 78.23.12.45" (just an example). How would you set these IPs in `environment.development` and `environment` to have access the API in both local network and Internet?

Comment: Read the link in my answer, if the answer not enough. The access has nothing to do with the environments. The build version use the environment, the ng serve version use the environment.development.